# "ImportError: No module named jobs.models" with relative path

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

django 1.4,python 2.6.6.
I have an app "jobs".
my files tree:

```
djproject/
|-- djproject
|   |-- db
|   |   `-- tdata.db
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- jobs
|   |   |-- admin.py
|   |   |-- admin.pyc
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |   |-- models.py
|   |   |-- models.pyc
|   |   |-- tests.py
|   |   `-- views.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
`-- manage.py
```

my manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Then I run "python manage.py shell" in which is the same level folder with file "manage.py".
And then I type "from jobs.models import Job".
Errors as follow(relative path):

```
>>> from jobs.models import Job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jobs.models
```

but, If I use full path

```
>>> from djproject.jobs.models import Job
```

error disapear, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as expected because you're now running `manage.py` from a different directory than in previous versions of Django. See [Updated default project layout and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py) in the Django documentation for more details.

You're now starting `manage.py` from a higher directory in the tree so you'll need to include `djproject` when importing the code. The documentation also gives a suggestion on how to do it differently (if you want):

> Anything imported as a top-level module can be placed adjacent to the
>   new manage.py. For instance, to decouple "myapp" from the project
>   module and import it as just myapp, place it outside the mysite/
>   directory:

```
manage.py
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Comment: but the folders tree is produced by "django-admin.py startproject djporject".

Comment: That's true, it's just that the location of `manage.py` has changed which means you'll need to include the name of the project when importing a module.

Comment: New error. I thought I have solve the problem using "mv" jobs folder out. But I get error:Error: No module named jobs, When I type "python manage.py shell", Why?

Comment: got it.I need to modify my settings.py ethier,modify "djproject.jobs" as "jobs"

Answer (score 0):

Moving *manage.py* 1 level down (inside djproject/djproject/) should help. Then You'll be able to import modules as You want:

```
from jobs.models import Job
```

Comment: inside djproject/djproject ? it is not recommended. When you said "1" level ,did you mean top level?

Comment: 1 level down from actual position (from *djproject/* to *djproject/djproject/*). Then manage.py is in the same level as Your apps etc, so You can import it as You wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/python/djproject/djproject')
```

After I add this into setting.py, it works.(as Internal Server Error said.)
and I "mv" myapp(jobs) to same folder with manage.py ,it works either.(as Simeon Visser said.)

Comment: new errors, after I the "mv" option.Error: No module named jobs

Comment: got it.I need to modify my settings.py ethier,modify "djproject.jobs" as "jobs"